# Git: How to pull from another repository without adding a merge commit

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge, git-pull, git-fetch

This is a project where multiple developers are working.  Assume that all work is done on the master branch, and that there is a remote repo that has the following history today:

```
A --- B --- C
```

Today I went ahead and cloned this repository into one of my sandboxes (let's call this `work_sb01`).  I did some work, and have committed my changes locally (there could be just one commit or multiple commits).  The Git history for this sandbox looks as shown below:

```
A --- B --- C --- X
```

Two days from today, I clone the same repository into another sandbox (let's call it `work_sb02`).  As expected, the repo `HEAD` has moved, so the history might now look something like this:

```
A --- B --- C --- D --- E
```

I need to be able to pull the changes that I made in `work_sb01` and bring them into `work_sb02`.  I'm currently doing this with the following command:

```
cd <path_to_work_sb02>
git pull <path_to_work_sb01> master
```

This gets the job done, but it creates a merge commit.  I have now a requirement to avoid adding merge commits into the project Git log.  How can I pull the changes from `work_sb01` and make them the most recent commit in the history?  In other words, the local history for `work_sb02` should look like the one shown below:

```
A --- B --- C --- D --- E --- X
```

Comment: `git pull` is a convenience command that means "run `git fetch`, then run a second command, usually `git merge`". If you don't want to run `git merge`, don't run it. In my opinion, the best way to not run `git merge` here is to avoid `git pull` as well, though you can instruct `git pull` to use `git rebase` as its second command. Note that rebase won't actually put `X` itself after `E`, but rather, will copy `X` (which still comes after `D`) to a *new* (and improved?) commit `X'` that comes after `E`.

Comment: Right, I also tried `git pull --rebase <path_to_work_sb01> master`.  However, in that case the local history becomes `A --- B --- C --- X --- D --- E`.  I'm hoping there is a another way to do it so that my history has the order that I need.

Comment: If you do the fetch and rebase steps separately, you have a lot more control, so that you can get the order you want (with `X'` at the end). You'll `git checkout` the branch where you want to throw away your old `X` and replace it with the new, improved `X'`, then tell Git to rebase *that branch* using the fetched `origin/<name>`. When you use `git pull`, it combines everything into one convenient command that, alas, doesn't do what you *want*, so just don't combine them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the right way to do this from work_sb02:

```
cd <path_to_work_sb02>
git remote add sb01 <path_to_work_sb01> 
git fetch sb01 
git checkout master 
git rebase --onto master master sb01/master
```

Answer (score 0):

If doing in `path_to_work_sb02` a `pull --rebase path_to_work_sb01` does not give you the right order, you could... consider doing the opposite:

- pull --rebase `path_to_work_sb02` from `path_to_work_sb01` path.
- rename `path_to_work_sb01` as `path_to_work_sb02`
- change its remote `origin` URL
- go on working from there.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do this.  This is a clever idea, but I need to be able to do everything from `work_sb02`, without making any changes in `work_sb01`.

Comment: @AndresM Simply duplicate work_sb01, and leave the original one untouched.